# Ordering inside the priority_queue

Tags: c++

My priority_queue is ordered backwards and I don't understand why. This is from [cplusplus.com](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/queue/priority_queue/)

> The expression comp(a,b), where comp is an object of this type and a
>   and b are elements in the container, shall return **true** if **a is
>   considered to go before b** in the strict weak ordering the function
>   defines.

Now in my Comparator's class operator() function, a should go before b if a is less then b. Therefore I return true if a is less then b. However in the end I get the sequence "321", but I excpected "123" instead!

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

class Number{
    int x;
public:
    Number(int _x):x(_x){}
    int getX()const{return x;}
};

class Comparator{
public:
    bool operator()(const Number& a,const Number& b){
        if (a.getX()<b.getX()){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};

int main(){
    priority_queue<Number,vector<Number>,Comparator> pq;
    pq.push(2);
    pq.push(1);
    pq.push(3);

    while (!pq.empty()){
        cout<<pq.top().getX();
        pq.pop();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You know you can say `return a.getX() < b.getX();` right?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That website also says:

> the element popped is the last according to this strict weak ordering

So the elements are popped in the reverse order of the weak ordering. This is because `priority_queue` implements a max-heap, i.e. a heap which pops the maximum element (as defined by the weak ordering) first.

If you want to implement a min-heap (one which will pop the elements from minimum to maximum), you need to make your comparison function do the opposite, i.e. return `true` if and only if`a > b` according to your ordering.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing your `Comparator`:

```
class Comparator{
public:
    bool operator()(const Number& a,const Number& b){
        if (a.getX()<b.getX()){
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
};
```

To something like this:

```
struct Comparator { 
    bool operator()(Number const &a, Number const &b) { 
        return b.getX() < a.getX();
    }
};
```

At least to me, your `Number` looks pretty suspect as well. I think I'd probably eliminate it entirely and just use `int` directly. If, for some reason you insist on using a class I'd consider supporting conversion to `int`:

```
class Number {
    int x;
public:
    Number(int x) : x(x) {}
    operator int() const { return x; }
};
```

...which simplifies the `Comparator` class to:

```
class Comparator { 
    bool operator()(Number const &a, Number const &b) { 
        return b < a;
    }
};
```

...but that's equivalent to `std::greater`, so you might as well just use that directly so your collection definition looks like this:

```
priority_queue<Number,vector<Number>, greater<Number> > pq;
```